# Grails Many-To-Many - Problems of dynamic finder

Tags: grails, many-to-many, fetch, dynamic-finders

I hope you can help me guys. Google unfortunately didn't helps me out and my search here at stackoverflow didn't as well :-(

I have two DomainClasses **HumanResource** and **Task** with a many-to-many relationship.

Model-Definitions:

**Task**:

```
class Tasks {

    String name

    static belongsTo = [HumanResource]
    static hasMany = [humanResources: HumanResource]
    //also tried but didn't help -> static fetchMode = [humanResources:"eager"]
}
```

**HumanResource**:

```
class HumanResource {

    String name

    static hasMany = [tasks: Tasks]

}
```

I also tried to add an index on the id-field with mapping={} but I also think that's not the solution, it didn't help and I think there is already an index on the id-field.

So, what I did and not works is now to find all human resources for the given tasks! And the tasks comes from Services and they are already fetched in the service model with "static fetchMode = [tasks:"eager"]"!

Controller-Code:

```
def listHumanResourcesFromTasks = {
        def list = HumanResource.findAllByTasks(service.getTasks())

        //and I tried also with an own HashMap but didn't work as well

}
```

I always get an error "**org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException**" with an SQL-GrammarException. But I really don't know why. The "service.getTasks()" objects are fully filled (as I wrote with fetchMode = [tasks:"eager"])...

It would be awesome if somebody could give me the winning hint.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Best wishes,

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of query isn't supported - you'd need to use HQL or a criteria query in general. But this particular one is easy since you have a bidirectional relationship. You can get all of the `HumanResource` instances for a collection of `Tasks` with this:

```
def resources = service.getTasks().collect { it.humanResources }.flatten() as Set
```

It needs to be a `Set` since the same `HumanResource` instance may appear multiple times so you need to condense the List into unique instances.

Comment: Hey Burt, thanks a lot, that works! But I have a continuative Question. If I use your solution the "HumanResource" Model is filled completly and a lot of unnecessary hibernate selects will be performed. How can I "exclude" this with your solution or how can I delegate "what to collect" with your solution? I tried **def resources = service.getTasks().collect{humanResources.id; humanResources.firstName; humanResources.lastName}.flatten() as Set** but with this I get (in case of 5 resources) 15 results unordered and not related to each other :-( Can you give me a hint? Thanks again!Marco